# How to replace a string value using Vue.js mixins?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins, vue-component

I have created a mixins file called as urlMixin.js as show below,

```
module.exports = {
data() {
    return {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000'
    };
  }
}
```

I have a component called as profile.vue in which I have imported the mixin file. The profile.vue file looks like this,

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import urlMixin from './../../mixins/urlMixin';

export default{
    data() {
        return{
           
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        
    },

    mixins : [ urlMixin ],
    
    methods:{
        getInfo: function(){
            axios.get('this.url/profile')
            .then(response =>{
                
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to replace the url value in the Profile.vue with the url value present in urlMixin.js file, like how it is shown in the profile.vue file. Is there a way using which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ES6 you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert the value into the string:

```
axios.get(`${this.url}/profile`)
```

Or using plain Javascript:

```
axios.get(this.url + '/profile')
```